# SBT 0.10 tutorial

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm very interested in Scala and have a great book on it, but I can't find any good tutorials on how to use SBT and their github page isn't very intuitive for people new to it. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039271/beginners-guide-to-sbt-0-10-and-idea might be useful

Comment: The github page is full of documentation and examples, and the basic steps are all [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Setup). I suggest you turn your questions into actual questions of how to do something or what does something mean.

Comment: The [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Welcome) at github is actually highly readable if one patiently ploughs through it. Well worth the effort and highly recommended!

Answer (score 7):

A quick Google search found these results, in addition the [GitHub page](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) you mentioned:

- [Getting started with Scala using SBT](http://chrismoos.com/2010/02/10/getting-started-with-scala-using-sbt/)
- [Using SBT on your Scala Maven project for continous testing](http://macstrac.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-sbt-on-your-scala-maven-project.html)
- [Building Android apps in Scala with sbt](http://zegoggl.es/2009/12/building-android-apps-in-scala-with-sbt.html)
- [an unofficial guide to sbt 0.10](http://eed3si9n.com/sbt-010-guide)

Some may not be relevant depending on the situation you're using it in, but I figured I'd link them anyway just in case.

Comment: The unofficial guide appears to be japanese (well, non-english anyway), which should be noted.  And the others appear to be non-0.10 based, which essentially means they're not very applicable.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. It was in English when I looked it, and still is in Google cache from a few days ago: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WkXtRswLX1wJ:eed3si9n.com/sbt-010-guide+an+unofficial+guide+to+sbt+0.10&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fr&client=firefox-a

Comment: Both, an English and a Japanese version are available.

Comment: @Antoras: Yeah, now it's like that. Before, when I posted the comment and modified my answer, the English version had been replaced by Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this presentation](http://sbt010.lessis.me/#0) from NY scala enthusiasts meetup could be good start. Actually, it is more overview than manual.

Inside:

- Demo
- The theory
- Quick Configuration DSL
- How to port a plugin
- Project dependencies

(Use <- and -> to browse through the slides).

Answer (score 1):

Since 2011, you now (Dec. 2016) also have **[Essential SBT](https://www.scalawilliam.com/essential-sbt/)** from [**William Narmontas**](https://twitter.com/ScalaWilliam).

> The aim of this is to show you how SBT can be simple to get started with, and how to get production level iterations going.
>   We don't aim to build a strong understanding of SBT - there are plenty of other materials online for this.

That tutorial comes with its [own video too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI0i7f2byPY).