# sbt version and scala version. project configuration for intellij idea with sbt-idea plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039271/beginners-guide-to-sbt-0-10-and-idea) steps to configure a project for IntelliJ idea.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0")
```

I use [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) for sbt version 0.12 with fixed [bug](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/commit/16398d9fc44ce892a652cb3c55f437fb5d0be3c0) for Idea.

When I type `sbt` in my project's directory, I noticed that it uses scala 2.9.2.. but I'm going to use scala 2.10.1 for my project.

Questions:

Does it make sense which scala version to use for plugin(s) (`~/.sbt/plugins`)-compilation, or I should use one/same scala version for everything? Can I change scala version for plugins?

So, I created `~/.sbt/plugin/build.sbt` file with mentioned content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I got it.

1. if you have a project with `build.sbt` (that uses 2.10.1 scala) file - as soon as you type `sbt`.. all dependencies will be downloaded into `~/.sbt` folder - even scala compiler will be downloaded there (`~/.sbt/boot`). It could be even several version of scala: 2.10.1 and 2.9.2 for example.
2. and about sbt-idea and `~/sbt/plugins` .. it could any scala version - depending on its `build.sbt` file, for example in my case:

> resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at
>   "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
>
> ```
> addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT")
> ```

I should notice if try different version.. like [1.1.0-M2-TYPESAFE](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.1.0-M2-TYPESAFE/) it will not work.. (at least in my case) - `gen-idea` command is not available then. I do not know why. I guess it should.

Also if you do not point `resolvers +=` - it will will not work.. but it it will not tell you about that..

This plugin is using scala 2.9.2 - we can not see it here, but we can see it from that outputs it produces while installing/downloading. That's why we have `~/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/` as a result.

**In any case we should not care about it. It is handled by sbt.**

When you converted your sbt-project into your intellij-idea project by typing `gen-idea` in sbt console, as the result your IDE project will be referencing to `~/.sbt/scala` but not to your  somewhere-installed-scala.. So even no need to pointing the scala location - that [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) sbt's plugin will do all the work. And that's good!

That's the answer I wanted to get. One gets/understands it by trying it.

Answer (score 2):

that version is out of date, it depends on sbt-idea 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT. The latest at the time of writing is 1.3.0

See my project [skeleton](https://github.com/fractal/skeleton) for an implementation using the latest versions of scala, scalatest and SBT to IDE project plugins.